# How can I make gap between parent and child or each childs same?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I want to create a flexbox component that spacing between each child components and the spacing between parent and child are all the same. It's similar to 'space-evenly' but i don't want to use static height value in flexbox. How can I create this flexbox?

```
<Col>
  {/* child components */}
</Col>
```

[image]

I tried 'gap' property to make it but it doesn't contain space between parent component and child component.
I also tried 'space-evenly' option in 'justify-content' property but it doesn't have any space unless i put a static value of height.
What should I do for spacing evenly and automatically adjusting height as child component's height at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can use the property `justify-content`. An option for this property is `"space-between"`, which will use `100%` of the space, but will put equal spaces between the objects.

You can also use `"space-around"`, or `"space-evenly"` which have similar effects, so play around with these and see if they meet your criteria.

Remember that this property must be specified in the parent component, which must have `display: flex`.